# screen position relative to center android

Tags: android, automation, adb, ui-automation, resolution

Good afternoon.

**What I've done :**
Changed screen resolution!

Was - adb shell wm size 1200x1920
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGiOW.jpg)

And so I did - adb shell wm size 900x1920
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SZZW.jpg)

**Now I need to raise the desktop so that there is no black frame on the top and a large one on the bottom.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiLd0.jpg)

**How to do it? Help me please! I beg you very much!**
I have all root permissions.

I have tried commands - adb shell wm overscan, ADB shell wm density
But all this did not help me to raise the screen up from the center